# C fprintf writing multiple lines to file?

Tags: c

I have school project in Linux and I need to create a user defined text file which has 1000 random numbers between 100-999.

I managed to create user defined file by using array and my code has no errors but when I run it I only have one number in my file but I want to have 1000 numbers I use \n but its not working please help me ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char dosya[MAX];
    printf("\nLütfen dosya adı giriniz:");
    scanf("%s",dosya);
    fp=fopen(dosya,"w");
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++);
    {

        int sayi;

        sayi=rand()%999-100;
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n",sayi);
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this in my file there is only one number so I think it keeps writing on the same line for 1000 times (but there is /n) where is the rest I checked the for loop and its working please help me ?

Comment: why are you closing the file at the end of each iteration?

Comment: Your example is broken (missing }), but it looks like you are closing the file and bailing out in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: I fixed that I am closing the file after the for loop still nothing...

Comment: 2 deleted answers that say the same thing.  That's why you indent your code

Comment: You have a `;` at the end of your `for` loop. Remove it.

Comment: I am closing my file after the for loop that was a copy paste error so close file is after the for loop its not in the for loop.

Comment: Just btw, `rand()%999` will give you a number in the range `[0,998]`, not `[100,999]`

Comment: the ; end of the loop what the hell it fixed it thank you so much I dont know where it come from anyway why that ; cause this problem ?

Comment: @BugraSezer it is because that is like saying `for( ... ){}`

Comment: I fixed the code to 999-100 will it create numbers between 999-100 this time ?

Comment: @BugraSezer no. modulus has higher order of operation so that is like saying `(rand()%999)-100`. Think what the modulus function does and then how to use that to give you a number between 100-999. Hint: `(rand% ?what goes here? ) + 100`

Comment: I dont understand what do I need to write in order to get numbers between 100-999 ? edit: it makes me get - numbers ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove semicolon after for loop.

When you execute your code all after all `1000`  iterations only one time your block after for loop executes.

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++);  
                    ^^
```

Comment: I want to create numbers between 999 - 100 so sayi=rand()%999-100; is it works ?

Comment: @BugraSezer `sayi=rand()%999-100;` this won't work. because when you get reminder 10 resultant would be -90. and you can try `rand()%899 +100`

Answer (score 3):

In C, all instructions are terminated in a semicolon

Your "for" statement has a semicolon at the end, which is interpreted as a "do nothing" instruction.

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++);
```

Remove the trailing semicolon and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You are terminating the for loop just after you creating it. remove the semicolon on the line below.

for (i=0;i<1000;i++);

Your final code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int main(){
FILE *fp;
char dosya[MAX];
printf("\nLütfen dosya adı giriniz:");
scanf("%s",dosya);
fp=fopen(dosya,"w");
int i;
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){ 
    int sayi;
    sayi=rand()%999;
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
    fprintf(fp,"%d\n",sayi);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

}